# Парсинг данных из файла

Tags: php, парсер

Короче, делал я одну вещь и решил, что не хочу использовать БД, а попробовать сделать всё через файлы. Так вот. Регистрацию в файл я сделал, с проверкой всего, что надо, все как полагается. Но проблема со входом. Структура файла с данными пользователей такая:

```
    |-ник-пароль
```

Так вот. Пытаюсь парсить через кучу explod'ов и foreach'ей, вот что выходит:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lcnick']=stripslashes($_POST['nick']);
$r=file_get_contents('users.dat');
$rr=explode('|',$r);
foreach ($rr as $v1)
{
$rrr=explode('-',$v1);
if ($rrr['0']==$_SESSION['lcnick'] && $rrr['1']==$_POST['pass'])
{
$_SESSION['cnick']=$_SESSION['lcnick'];
header('index.php');
}
}
?>
```

cnick - основной ник пользователя, lcnick - временная переменная ника. Короче, после мучительного дебага я выяснил, что не работает парсинг пароля из файла по второму признаку ("|"-первый признак - так парсится сам аккаунт (-ник-пароль), потом идет второй признак - "-", это нулевой индекс (Ник) и первый (Пароль). Так вот пароль и не хочет попадать в массив. Если кто-то разберется, то можете помочь?

Comment: Тег правильный. А в чем не хотение использовать БД?

Comment: Просто не хочу. Хотел подружиться с файлами.

Comment: Покажите содержвание users.dat, например.

Comment: Там есть только одна запись:

|-gorgilike-123

Comment: @gorguelike, вы сейчас столкнулись с очень важной штукой. Функционал чтения из файлов - как и база данных - должен лежать и работать отдельно от всего остального. Тогда вы сможете нормально его оттестировать и убедиться, что все работает верно, и только потом уже подцеплять внешние обработчики. Другими словами, вам нужен набор функций/методов, которые будут выдирать вам данные из файла (для начала хватит "выбрать все" и "выбрать с такими-то значениями таких колонок"). Что касается формата - я бы использовал csv, с ним все проще, с ним легче посмотреть работу соседней библиотеки и сравнить р-т

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если именно ваш код ковырять, то [примерно как-то так](http://ideone.com/tRmLgT)(заменить обратно переменные и пользоваться). А вообще Etki все правильно написал в комментарии.